# Are multiple self-types possible?

Tags: scala

I want to do the following, but the self-type line just doesn't compile. Do I have this syntax wrong or is this just impossible?

```
trait A {
  def aValue = 1
}
trait B {
  def bValue = 1
}
trait C {
  a : A, b : B =>
  def total = a.aValue + b.bValue
}

class T extends C with A with B { ...
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can have a single self-type which is a compound type.

Try this:

```
trait A {
  def aValue = 1
}
trait B {
  def bValue = 1
}
trait C {
  self: A with B =>
  def total = aValue + bValue
}

class ABC extends A with B with C
```

Answer (score 4):

With **one trait** you can do it with **structural type**:

```
trait C {
  self: { def aValue: Int
          def bValue: Int } =>

  def total = aValue + bValue
}

class ABC extends C {
  def aValue = 1
  def bValue = 1
}
```

Reflection used.

But, firstly you should not overuse self-types because of [principle of least power](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html).

Methods from question can be added simply by extending other tait:

```
trait C extends A with B{
  def total = aValue + bValue
}
```

or type both methods explicitly:

```
trait C {
  def aValue: Int
  def bValue: Int

  def total = aValue + bValue
}
```

**Where to use self-types?**

Self-types are usually used with classes. This is a good way for trait to require being a subclass of a desired class.

There is also one good use of self-type with triats: when you want to manipulate order of class initialization with multi-inheritance.